# Dynamic optional parameters in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Consider SQL query with all parameters being optional

```
SELECT ...
FROM Table
WHERE
 (@Col1 IS NULL OR Col1 = @Col1)
AND
 (@Col2 IS NULL OR Col2 = @Col2)
...
 (@ColN IS NULL OR ColN = @ColN)
```

There are about 8 parameters, but could be more in the future.

Code reviewer asked to never write such WHERE construction (check for NULL or equality) and instead use dynamic SQL (without giving a reason).

To me it looks readable and explicit.
I haven't run an execution plan yet, but theoretically DBMS would spot any parameter that is null and not consider second term within parenthesis. Thus I expect that only specified parameters would be compared.

1. Can somebody support or refute why this is bad?
2. Indexing. Can we even index such query (and how), if search parameters can arrive in any combination?

Comment: "Never" is an unusual word to use when it comes to SQL. Personally I would use the SQL you've written unless it starts performing badly. Dynamic SQL, IMHO, should never be ones first choice.Indexing such queries is very difficult. In my experience, even with such generalised search conditions, some have more relevance or are more likely to be used that others, so sometimes you can prefilter with the expected parameters.

Comment: Why not use something like

`WHERE  
 ( ISNULL(@Col1,Col1 )= Col1)
AND`
...

just to make the reviewer happy :)

Comment: Definitely prefer to "never" use dynamic sql. I've found its is almost always used by those who don't understand how to write SQL. Some edge cases as suggested in the answers, but that too can be solved.

Comment: Discussed in great detail in [Erland's dynamic search conditions](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: And Erland's page also discusses _parameter sniffing_ where the query optimizer uses the first set of parameters to build the optimized query which is then cached for reuse. Another reason to use `option ( recompile )`.

Answer (score 2):

It is complicated.  Having a non-dynamic query has some advantages:

- It is clearly understood.
- It is easier to debug and maintain.
- It is validated when a stored procedure is created.
- SQL Server will maintain dependencies for you if the code is in a stored procedure.

From a coding perspective, I think the compile-time validation is a big win.  It can prevent unexpected run-time failures.

The dynamic query has one advantage in this case:  it is probably going to be recompiled each time it is executed.

When would this make a difference?  If you had an index on each of the columns being used, then recompiling would always help.

However, you can get the best of both worlds using `option (recompile)`.  This will recompile the code based on the current parameter values.  This is probably the best option for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with your reviewer. Here's why:

The risk with what you have is SQL Server will compile this query **once**, at first execution. It will make cardinality estimates based on the parameter values supplied at that time, and base the execution plan on that. This execution plan will stay in the cache for some time, regardless of what actually happens on subsequent runs. This can lead to really bad execution plans for some parameter values.

As Mr Linoff suggests (and he *really* knows his stuff), you can account for this with `option(recompile)`. However, this means SQL Server will need to recompile this query on *every* execution. If these queries are run often, it can cause SQL Server to spend a lot of extra effort recompiling over time.

Furthermore, my experience with this type of query is users will tend to supply certain columns much more often than others. If you build the query dynamically, SQL Server can cache plans for the common permutations, and save that extra recompile work. From a DBA perspective, these are now also separate entries in the plan cache, which you can check to get an idea for which indexes might be more valuable to support this search feature over time.

Of course, knowing whether or not this will be a win means knowing your data, your system, and your users. You have to do the work to go back and check whether users really do search on the same sets of columns, or whether its more randomly distributed.

Where I might also do things differently is I would tend to build that dynamic SQL in client code, where it sounds a bit like you're expecting to do this as part of a stored procedure.

For example, with C#-alike pseudocode:

```cs
sql = "SELECT ... FROM... WHERE 1=1";

if (txtCol1.Text != "")
{
   sql += " AND Col1 = @Col1"
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col1", txtCol1.Text);
}
if (txtCol1.Text != "")
{
    sql += " AND Col2 = @Col2"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Col2", txtCol2.Text);
}
//...
// Note this is just pseudocode. I'm not a fan of AddWithValue() in actual practice.

cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I know the `1=1` thing seems weird, but it doesn't hurt SQL Server, and it's a simple way to make sure the syntax is still valid regardless which (if any) of the further conditions is the first to hold a value.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yet each column search parameter corresponds to the UI search panel control - and this makes it unpredictable on what users will search by.

Comment: @Nickolodeon You don't need to predict which fields will matter. The Sql Server plan cache will do the work of keeping the important plans in the cache for you. All you need to do is write the code to include the fields selected by the user (and only those fields) in your query.

Comment: @Nickolodeon I added some sample code to explain how this might work.